# Typeerror: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript, css, null, typeerror

I am using JavaScript and the below line gives me a type error.

```
if (btnvar1.style.color=="white")
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
```

**HTML**

I am using Tailwind as CSS and Font Awesome for icons.

```
<div>
<button onclick="toggle1()" id="lovebtn1" class="btn bg-transparent border-none p-0 text-white hover:cursor-pointer"><i class="fa-solid fa-heart text-3xl"></i></button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var btnvar1=document.getElementById("lovebtn1");

function toggle1(){
    if (btnvar1.style.color=="white"){
        btnvar1.style.color="red";
    }
    else{
        btnvar1.style.color="white";
    }
}
```

I was trying to make a love react button like Instagram but without the animation using JavaScript.And I was trying to set a condition to change the color of the icon.